# Сложение без арифметических операторов

Tags: java, циклы

```
        while(y != 0) {
        int carry = x & y;
        x = x ^ y;
        y = carry << 1;
    }
```

Объясните пожалуйста как работает этот цикл.

Comment: Что именно в нем непонятно?

Comment: @defaultlocale, то, как сочетание подобных побитовых операций приводит к результату, аналогичному таковому после сложения.

Comment: @Arhad в этом случае автору имеет смысл задать вопрос по алгоритму (Почему цикл с побитовым И и сдвигом эквивалентен сложению? И эквивалентен ли?). Тогда отвечающим не потребуется расписывать значение цикла и операторов. И напротив, если автору непонятно что делает та или иная конструкция языка, то имеет смысл задать по ней более конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Извиняюсь за неправильно сформулированный вопрос... интересует строка x = x ^ y;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> интересует строка `x = x ^ y`

^ - означает битовую операцию исключающего или (XOR):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примечательность XOR состоит в том, что двойное применение XOR восстанавливает первичный результат, то есть

```
X==(X^Y)^Y
```

Comment: Ну это про сам *xor*. Однако по вопросу складывается впечатление, что автора интересует, как он в сочетании с ещё парой операций заменяет собой арифметическое сложение. Хотя, вопрошающий принял этот ответ, так что странно как то...